# Can I use single code base for web development and mobile applications?

Tags: django, flutter, cross-platform

I am searching for a technology, a framework or a library, etc. That can help me make:
Website (not web app), Android and IOS app. (with a single code base)

Kindly also clear :

1. I learned Django. Can it help me ?
2. Flutter is used for Android and IOS apps. If I learn flutter, will I need to write code for website separately ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter-web is in beta, but might work for most (if not all) of your applications.  If you use Flutter-web, you'll have one code base.  You need to make sure your app is "responsive": not just at startup time, but all the time, since the web window can change size at will.  Luckily, you have things like LayoutBuilder to help you.